# In a method, how to use a default argument in abscence of second parameter in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def alphabetize(arr,rev=false)
    if rev
        arr.sort!{|a,b| b<=>a}
    else
        arr.sort!
    end

    puts arr
end

alphabetize([5,3,8,1],false)
```

This is a code which I am supposed to submit on a codecademy exercise, but upon submission I get the following error:

> It looks like your method doesn't default to alphabetizing an array when it doesn't receive a second parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `false` argument so you have on your last line:

`alphabetize([5,3,8,1])`

or this worked for me:

```
def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
    arr.sort!
    if rev
        arr.reverse!
    else
        arr
    end
end

numbers = [5,7,2,3]

alphabetize(numbers)
puts numbers
```

Comment: What's the specific exercise?

Comment: codecademy/ruby/unit-5/second-part of unit 5/lesson-4

Comment: @PranjalMisra great:)

Answer (score 0):

You should puts return value from this method outside

```
def alphabetize(arr,rev=false)
  if rev
    arr.sort!{|a,b| b<=>a}
  else
    arr.sort!
  end
  arr
end

puts alphabetize(['d', 'c', 'a', 'b'])
```

If you puts the arr inside the method, the method will return nil, not arr itself. For example:

```
irb(main):001:0> def test()
irb(main):002:1>   puts "hello"
irb(main):003:1> end
=> :test
irb(main):004:0> a = test()
hello
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> a
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> def test()
irb(main):007:1>   "hello"
irb(main):008:1> end
=> :test
irb(main):009:0> a = test()
=> "hello"
```